# Innertext a specific "src" address using MSXML2.xmlHttp

Tags: excel, vba, innertext, outerhtml

Using MSXML2.xmlHttp on a specific webpage I’m able with the code bellow debug.print  all “SRC” adresses, it brings me 6 “src” adresses. Now I’m trying to innertext into excel  - range(“A3”) only the third “src” address.  Any help would be nice.

```
Dim s As String, obj As Object, resp As String

    With CreateObject("HTMLFile")
        .write sResp

        For Each obj In .body.document.getElementsByTagName("img")
            Debug.Print obj.outerHTML
        Next

    End With
```

Comment: `Range(“A3”).Value = .body.document.getElementsByTagName("img")(2).src`

Comment: I try this before, but the 3th src address is inside a "Table", so I have "loop" throughout the table to reach it. It would be fine if I could innerterxt all "src" into excel this would solve my source.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` should find all images, regardless of where they are in the document, so I'm not following what the problem is here.

Comment: I got this trying: "vba error 91 object variable or with block variable not set"

Comment: I can't unpick that without the full context of your code...